# SQL performance searching for long strings

Tags: mysql, string, hash, user-agent

I need to store user agent strings in a database for tracking and comparing customer behavior and sales performance between different browsers. A pretty plain user agent string is around 100 characters long. It was decided to use a `varchar(1024)` for holding the useragent data in the database. (I know this is overkill, but that's the idea; it's supposed to accommodate useragent data for years to come and some devices, toolbars, applications are already pushing 500 characters in length.) The table holding these strings will be normalized (each distinct user agent string will only be stored once) and treated like a cache so we don't have to interpret user agents over and over again.

The typical use case is:

- User comes to our site, is detected as being a new vistor
- New session information is created for this user
- Determine if we need to analyze the user agent string or if we have a valid analysis on file for it
- If we have it, great, if not, analyze it (currently, we plan on calling a 3rd party API)
- Store the pertinent information (browser name, version, os etc.) in a join table tied the existing user session information and pointing to the cache entry

**Note:** I have a tendency to say 'searching' for the user agent string in the database because it's not a simple look up. But to be clear, the queries are going to use '=' operators, not regexes or LIKE % syntax.

So the speed of looking up the user agent string is paramount. I've explored a few methods of making sure it will have good performance. Indexing the whole column is right out for size reasons. A partial index isn't such a good idea either because most user agents have the distinguishing information at the end; the partial index would have to be fairly long to make it worthwhile by which point its size is causing problems.

So it comes down to a hash function. My thought is to hash the user agent string in web server code and run the select looking for the hash value in the database. I feel like this would minimize the load on the database server (as opposed to having it compute the hash), especially since if the hash isn't found, the code would turn around and ask the database to compute the hash again on the insert.

Hashing to an integer value would offer the best performance at the risk of higher collisions. I'm expecting to see thousands or tens of thousands user agents at the most; even 100,000 user agents would fit reasonably well into a 2^32 size integer with very few collisions which could be deciphered by the webservice with minimal performance impact. Even if you think an integer hash isn't such a good idea, using a 32 character digest (SHA-1, MD5 e.g.) should be much faster for selects than the raw string, right?

My database is MySQL InnoDB engine. The web code will be coming from C# at first and php later (after we consolidate some hosting and authentication) (not that the web code should make a big difference).

Let me apologize at this point if you think this is lame choose-my-hash-algorithm question. I'm really hoping to get some input from people who've done something similar before and their decision process. So, the question:

- Which hash would you use for this application?
- Would you compute the hash in code or let the db handle it?
- Is there a radically different approach for storing/searching long strings in a database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea of hashing long strings to create a token upon which to lookup within a store (cache, or database) is a good one. I have seen this done for extremely large strings, and within high volume environments, and it works great.

"Which hash would you use for this application?"

- I don't think the encryption (hashing) algorithm really matters, as you are not hashing to encrypt data, you are hashing to create a token upon which to use as a key to look up longer values. So the choice of hashing algorithm should be based off of speed.

"Would you compute the hash in code or let the db handle it?"

- If it were my project, I would do the hashing at the app layer and then pass it through to look up within the store (cache, then database).

"Is there a radically different approach for storing/searching long strings in a database?"

- As I mentioned, I think for your specific purpose, your proposed solution is a good one.

Table recommendations (demonstrative only):

`user`

- id int(11) unsigned not null
- name_first varchar(100) not null

`user_agent_history`

- `user_id` int(11) unsigned not null
- `agent_hash` varchar(255) not null

`agent`

- `agent_hash` varchar(255) not null
- `browser` varchar(100) not null
- `agent` text not null

Few notes on schema:

- From your OP it sounds like you need a M:M relationship between user and agent, due to the fact that a user may be using Firefox from work, but then may switch to IE9 at home. Hence the need for the pivot table.
- The varchar(255) used for `agent_hash` is up for debate. MySQL [suggests](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) using a varbinary column type for storing hashes, of which there are several types.
- I would also suggest either making `agent_hash` a primary key, or at the very least, adding a UNIQUE constraint to the column.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback. If I do end up going with a hash with an output greater than 8 bytes (`bigint`), I'll certainly look into the `varbinary` type. One thing I was reading about was using a longer hash function and XOR-ing the high and now ends together. This would have the advantage of letting me use a built-in, common hash algorithm but with a small output size for faster searching. Coupled with the idea of also storing the length of the user agent string, I think I would still have very good collision avoidance.

Comment: Each user session will get its own user agent entry, so those tables will remain one to one. Switching browsers, locations etc. requires a new session for our security purposes. Agent hash will have to remain non-unique, non-primary; I don't expect many collisions, but over the years there will be a non-zero amount and it has to be designed around.

Comment: What do you mean by 'built-in, common hash algorithm'? Built into MySQL? Also, your user tracking table will be transitory, like a session tracking table? You could set up your app to log new agents, with associated hashes, so when a user starts a new session, you create a hash from the user-agent, and compare it to your `agent` table, if it doesn't exist you can add it.

Comment: I mean a hash algorithm that's included with the development platforms in use on our servers. Right now, we have C#, MSSQL, MySQL and PHP in wide deployment; hash algorithms common to those are MD5, RipeMD and the SHA family. I would like to go with a 32 bit hash digest, but I can't find any options that wouldn't require including additional 3rd party libraries or custom code. User tracking tables will be permanent in our MySQL DB (for now, they may move). User agents and the properties of the browsers/devices they represent in their own table where each distinct UA will be stored once

Answer (score 1):

Your hash idea is sound. I've actually used hashing to speed up some searches on millions of records. A hash index will be quicker since each entry is the same size. md5 will likely be fine in your case and will probably give you the shortest hash length. If you are worried about hash collisions, you can add include the length of the agent string.